# Android LinearLayout given set of weights gives different column widths

Tags: android-layout-weight

Here is a `LinearLayout` with three columns with the centre column having half the weight of the other two -- the weights are 2, 1, 2, and the `weightSum` is 5.

I was expecting the centre column to be half as wide as the other two, but not so. Why?

[image]

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_height="72dp"
        android:weightSum="5">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:background="#555"
            android:textSize="36dp"
            android:margin="6dp"
            android:text="left"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#555"
            android:textSize="36dp"
            android:margin="6dp"
            android:text="center"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:background="#555"
            android:textSize="36dp"
            android:margin="6dp"
            android:text="right"/>

    </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Even more bizarrely, I have another example where the weights are also 2, 1, 2 and the centre column is wider than the outer ones. This makes no sense; what on Earth is going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the layout width of the textviews from "wrap_content" to "0dp" or if that failes to "match_parent"

Comment: That's done it! Why does that work? Is there any documentation about how `layout_width` changes the behaviour of `weight`?

Comment: If you are telling Android to use weight to layout your views, don't intervene by setting as limited space as possible with the "wrap  content" which messes up the layout.

Comment: So is `wrap_content` generally a bad idea? I'm using it almost everywhere and finding it exceptionally difficult to make a layout (compared, say, to HTML or WinForms).

Comment: It's not a bad idea, but you gotta know when and where to use it. It is just matter of conforming to the convention while achieving the tasks you need. You couldn't use it with weights but there are other crucial use cases for it.

Comment: Is _the convention_ documented anywhere? (New to Android development and finding it very unpleasant.)

Comment: Have you tried the Android developer website, plus most of this will come as you gain more experience, so just keep on developing you will get the hang of things, maybe even set your own conventions for your app.

Comment: developer.android.com ? It's really awful.

Comment: Yea its over whelming at times but that's why you gotta start small, just stick to YouTube tutorials and build up experience, at some point you will find your self understanding documentation.